# Sending data from C to python

Tags: python, c

I have some C code running on an embedded processor, which outputs integers (16 bits) over a serial port (stdout) using `printf("%d", my_int);`. I have some python code running on a PC that reads the serial stream using pyserial and writes it to a file, which I can just achieve using `ser.readline()`. This works quite happily, although it isn't very efficient.

As the embedded C is sending quite a lot of numbers and I want to cut down on the transfer time, I would like to send the data formatted as binary rather than ascii (i.e. two bytes/chars rather than several bytes/chars.) I tried to do this with:

```
char msbs = my_int>>8;
char lsbs = my_int;
printf("%c%c\n", msbs, lsbs)
```

And then in my python code:

```
chars = ser.readline()
value = ord(chars[0])<<8 + ord(chars[1])
```

But value seems to be gibberish. Could anyone point out the thing(s) I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import struct
chars = ser.readline()[:-1]
value = struct.unpack('>h', chars)
```

I've assumed that your integer is signed short and please note the presence of '>' for endianness (bytes order).

However the error with you code was because of operator precedence:
`value = (ord(chars[0])<<8) + ord(chars[1])` this should work. But it is better to use struct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> As the embedded C is sending quite a lot of numbers and I want to cut down on the transfer time,

To improve time performance you could send and/or receive more than one number at a time. In my tests, `array.fromfile()` is 10 - 100 times faster than `struct.unpack()`. It comes at the cost of calling `array.byteswap()` sometimes to take into account endianness explicitly.

---

If the C program and Python script were running on the same machine (same size, same endianess); then you could use `fwrite` to write short ints as platform values on C side and [`array.fromfile()` on Python side](http://docs.python.org/3/library/array#array.array.fromfile) to read them back in a native format.

For example, print short ints as binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  short a[] = {31415, 9265, 3589, 793};
  size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
  if (fwrite(&n, sizeof n, 1, stdout) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* send size */
  return (fwrite(a, sizeof *a, n, stdout) < n) ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Read it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import array
import struct

# make stdin binary
file = sys.stdin.detach()

# read size
size_format = 'N' # size_t
n, = struct.unpack(size_format, file.read(struct.calcsize(size_format)))
print(n)

a = array.array('h') # native short int
a.fromfile(file, n)
print(a.tolist()) # -> [31415, 9265, 3589, 793]
```

`array.fromfile` should be efficient both time and memory-wise. If you don't know the size then call `a.fromfile` until `EOFError` is raised.

---

If C program and Python script are on different machines then you could send integers in the network byte order:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netinet/in.h> /* htons() */

int main(void) {
  short a[] = {31415, 9265, 3589, 793};
  /* print one integer at a time */
  short *p = a, *end = &a[sizeof a / sizeof *a];
  for ( ; p != end; ++p) {
    uint16_t s = htons(*p); /* convert from native to network byte order */
    if (fwrite(&s, sizeof s, 1, stdout) != 1)  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And swap byte order if necessary on the Python side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import array
import sys

a = array.array('h') # short int in native byte order, byte swap might be needed
for i in range(15, 128): 
    try: # double size to avoid O(n**2) behaviour
        a.fromfile(sys.stdin, 2 << i)
    except EOFError:
        break
if sys.byteorder != 'big': # if not network order
    a.byteswap()  # swap byte order
print(a.tolist()) # -> [31415, 9265, 3589, 793]
```

To avoid converting to network order, you could send a magic number instead. It allows to send numbers in a native byte order on C side (as in the 1st code example) and check it in Python to swap bytes if necessary:

```
MAGIC = 1
if a[0] != MAGIC:
   a.byteswap()
   if a[0] != MAGIC:
      raise ValueError("Unexpected %d" % a[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `struct` idea is great, but your protocol is faulty.

If you write binary data, it is not useful to have line endings in-between: one of the "value bytes" could have that value - 10 - as well.

So better refrain from using these line ends and `readline()`.

But there could arise the problem that you could get out of sync. So you either should define a kind of package boundaries, or you could encode your data in more than 2 bytes.

Example: Each 16bit value is encoded in 3 bytes, in the following way:

```
AADDDDDD BBBDDDDD CCCDDDDD
```

`AA` is `10`, `BBB` is `110`, `CCC` is `111`.

The value 57723 - 0xE17B, 0b1110000101111011, is encoded as

```
10111000 11001011 11111011
```

or

```
B8 CB FB
```

by means of

```
byte1 = 0x80 + ((value >> 10) & 0x3F) # bits 10..15
byte2 = 0xC0 + ((value >> 5)  & 0x1F) # bits 5..9
byte3 = 0xE0 + ((value)       & 0x1F) # bits 0..4
```

Upon reception of these bytes, you immediately can detect

a) which byte it is (the 1st, the 2nd or the 3rd) and
b) its contents.

So even if one byte gets missing, you can detect that and can resume reception of the stream immediately.

Plus, this implementation is endianness-agnostic - it will work on every machine regardless of its endianness, a way every protocol should be designed.

How to implement that I'll leave to you.